# How to get memory address of an embedded slice in a struct?

Tags: go, struct

How can I get the memory address of an embedded slice in a struct?

Example:

```
type t1 struct {
    data string
}

type t2 struct {
    listData []t1
}
```

Now I want to know the memory address of `listData`. I couldn't figure out how to get the memory address out of it using the following:

```
newData := t2{}
newData.listData = append(newData.listData, t1{data:"mydata"})
printf("%p", &newData.listData) // this doesn't work, in fact it returns address of newData
```

Comment: "in fact it returns address of newData" - they're the same, addresses of a struct and its first field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listData` is the first field in the struct, its memory offset relative to the struct's address is zero, so they have the same address.

```
type t2 struct {
listData []string
moreData []int
}

func main() {
    var foo t2
    fmt.Printf("%p %p %p", &foo, &foo.listData, &foo.moreData)
}
```

> 0x43e260 0x43e260 0x43e26c

https://play.golang.org/p/FVMujcUHHYq